# How to plot with QwtPlot from Qt slot?

Tags: c++, qt, qwt

Good time of day! I have a question you'll maybe find silly and obvious, but i've already broke my head trying to solve this.

I want to plot some curve by pressing a QPushButton. I wrote the slot and connected it to the corresponding signal of this button. But when I click on it, nothing happens on the plot, although this function executes, and it can be viewed on the debugger and qDebug() output.

On the other hand, if you call this function directly, and not as a slot, it works perfectly. The only difference is the calling method: as a slot in first case and as a method in the second case.

Some code examples:

```
//Slot 
void MainWindow::buttonClick()
{
    qDebug() << "Enter";
    XRDDataReader *xrdr = new XRDDataReader();
    xrdr->fromFile("/home/hippi/Документы/Sources/Qt/49-3.xy");

    ui->plot->plotXRD(xrdr->xValues(), xrdr->yValues());
    qDebug() << "Quit";
}

void Plotter::plotXRD(QVector<double> x, QVector<double> y)
{
    QwtPlotCurve *curve = new QwtPlotCurve();
    curve->setRenderHint
                ( QwtPlotItem::RenderAntialiased, true );
    curve->setPen(Qt::black, 2);

    curve->setSamples(x,y);
    curve->attach(mainPlot);
}
```

Comment: Can you share the connection code as well?

Comment: Connection was made by Designer. Initially i used QAction and connect it like this
    connect(ui->actionOpen, SIGNAL(triggered()),this, SLOT(buttonClick()));

With the same effect.

Comment: and when you say it works if you call the function directly, you're talking about `buttonClick()` and not `plotXRD`, correct?

Comment: Yes, i call buttonClick() like an usual function and it works! But as a slot it won't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as autoreplotting is not enabled, you have to call replot to make changes happen.